# Power Automate - Send an email from a mailbox without "send on behalf of" displaying

Tags: email, power-automate, powerapps-forms, notifications, send-email

I have a Power Automate flow that sends email notifications out based on various conditions.  My client wants these emails to come from a specific mailbox (not my name or from Microsoft) - they want the "from" on the emails to read from ITPMO.  So I received Send As permissions to do that for that mailbox.  The problem is now that my name still appears on the emails, only now it says my name on behalf of ITPMO.  Is there any way I can remove my name from this?  Just have it be from ITPMO - rather than "on behalf of"?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please share the screen of Shared Mailboxes Permissions.I doubt yuo are having permissions 'Send on behalf of Permissions' instead of 'Send as permissions'

[image]

Also its not good to have your account to get 'Send as permissions' In case in future if you leave that company, then they need to look into this.
Best practice is to create new generic account and that account should have such kind of permissions.

Comment: I don't have the permissions myself to access the mailbox's settings.  But it looks like I was granted Send on behalf of" permissions.  I'll send a request to change that.  I'm wondering...if I leave the company can I just add someone else as a co-owner to the form (it's linked to a SharePoihnt list), would they be able to still send those emails?

Comment: Adding someone as co-owner is not the solution. Having those permissions to yourself can cause some audit issues as you would be able to open that inbox as well. It is always good to have some generic account having no inbox.

Comment: Good note, Saira.  I appreciate it